# How to make VS 2012 program to copy itself to startup folder in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, upstart

I want to make my super simple program to copy itself to the startup folder regardless if the os is w7/w8/w10 what I've done already is change the manifesto privileges with this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but I found no help for coding it in C# only in VB.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace Hello
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        player.URL = "hello.wav";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Hide();
        ShowInTaskbar = false;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string saobshtenie = "kp";
        string zaglavie = "zdr";
        MessageBox.Show(saobshtenie, zaglavie, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        player.controls.play();

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is you question? Show us your code.

Comment: I added the code but its nothing special...

Comment: You wouldn't normally copy an application into the startup folder. Normal usage would be to place a *shortcut* to the application there.

Comment: yh i forgot abb that but you got my idea